# Is it a good (or common) practice to use visibility indicator this way?

Tags: python

From [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/#descriptive-naming-styles) we know that single leading underscore in function name is "internal use" indicator, which means that this function is intended for internal use only and might be ignored by some `import`s.

Recently I started working on a project where I found a lot of places where class methods are defined in both versions and are used (for example) this way:

```py
class Proxy:
    def get_services(self):
        # Do something
        return self._get_services()

    def _get_services(self):
        # Do something more
```

I was told that this is supposed to tell other programmers that the `Proxy` object method `get_services` is expected to be used externally while the `_get_services` does some internal lower level work to get the services.

I always thought that function name should always tell exactly what the function is doing. Two different functions with names distinguished only by the underscore strike me automatically as a bad practice. On the other hand, I am new to Python and this usage makes certain sense, therefore if it is widely used without causing any confusion (or there are other advantages I'm not seeing), I can accept it as a part of the Python way of coding.

So, is this a common or recommended way of working with Python object methods?

Comment: Usually in such a case the function signature of the "private" and "public" method is different and when calling the "public" method it will fill in the required arguments for the "private" one (which could be awkward for the user to do it themselves). Hence a similar function name is justifiable since the methods do the same job, but require different inputs. Since in your example the signature is the same, most likely the return values will differ and `get_services` calls `_get_services` internally and returns a processed version of the output.

Comment: In such a case being more explicit wouldn't hurt, i.e. using different names that are more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you may not commonly see this, it is not bad practice; although, it does have specific use cases.

Normally methods can be broken into two parts, its public version and its private version. The public method basically adds an API layer which can then decide which private method to call or do some data manipulation on the inputs to conform it to meet the private methods requirements. The private method deals with handling the class private attributes themselves.

Adding this separation layer can be convenient.

Here is a basic example just to illustrate the idea. Though for something this simple you can just do it all in the single method.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None # Should be a string

    def set_a(self, a):
        if isinstance(a, str):
            self._set_a(a) # Set `a` since the input was a str
        else:
            self._set_a(str(a)) # Cast `a` to a str and set it

    def _set_a(self, str_a):
        self.a = str_a
```

For reference, normally when something like this is implemented it is called a [Facade Design Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-1)